# Completely hide deletions in latexdiff

Tags: latexdiff

I usually try to use `latexdiff` in a way that the diff result looks exactly as the revised document, just with colored highlights. But this does not always work, for example, when I merge paragraphs. This example illustrates my problem:

old.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    This is text in paragraph 1. This text will be deleted.

    This text here will also be deleted. That text here is in paragraph 2. Finally, everything shall be in one paragraph.
\end{document}
```

new.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    This is text in paragraph 1. That text here is in paragraph 2. Finally, everything shall be in one paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Then, I usually do this to show differences while hiding deletions:

```
echo \newcommand{\DIFdel}[1]{} > diff.tex
latexdiff old.tex new.tex >> diff.tex
```

But in the above example, this is the result:

```
\begin{document}
    This is text in paragraph 1. \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{This text will be deleted.
    }%DIFDELCMD < 

%DIFDELCMD <    %%%
\DIFdel{This text here will also be deleted. }\DIFdelend That text here is in paragraph 2. Finally, everything shall be in one paragraph.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in b.tex, everything is one paragraph, but this is not true in diff.tex. How can I fix that?

**Edit:** I have noticed that, while the two individual deletions are contained in two separate `\DIFdelbegin`s, they are wrapped in the same `\DIFdelbegin...\DIFdelend` block. So the `diff` seems to recognize that this is one big change, and `latexdiff` does something to split this into two changes, it seems. So maybe there is an option in `latexdiff` to not do that -- or maybe that would be a useful feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not a perfect solution, but this one works surprisingly well for me (on Windows):

```
echo \newcommand{\DIFdel}[1]{} > diff.tex
echo \RequirePackage{verbatim} >> diff.tex
latexdiff -s COLOR --disable-auto-mbox --exclude-textcmd="textit,footnote,section,subsection" --graphics-markup=0 --math-markup=0 old.tex new.tex ^
    | sed "s-\\\DIFdelbegin -\\\begin{comment}-g" ^
    | sed "s-\\\DIFdelend -\\\end{comment}\n-g" ^
    >> diff.tex
```